# Rasterize issue with ListDensityPlot in 12.1

Tags: plotting, graphics, image

I have upgraded to 12.1 (on OSX Catalina 10.15.3) and am noticing some odd behaviour with `Rasterize`.

If I use a high number of rasters when rasterising a `ListDensityPlot` the text on the axes and plot label gets scrambled. This (1) does not occur in 12.1 when rasterising a `ListPlot`, and (2) did not occur when the exact same code was run under 12.0.

Ultimately I am rasterising a bunch of plots and saving them out as eps format. However, here is a much more minimal piece of code which demonstrates the error.

```
lpd = ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All, PlotLabel -> "HELLO WORLD", FrameLabel -> {"HELLO WORLD", "HELLO WORLD"}];
lp = ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], PlotLabel -> "HELLO WORLD", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"HELLO WORLD", "HELLO WORLD"}];

numRaster = 4000;
Rasterize[lp, RasterSize -> numRaster]
Rasterize[lpd, RasterSize -> numRaster]
```

This gives the following images. Note if `numRaster = Automatic` the images look fine.

So yes, I understand that I can set `numRaster = Automatic`, but I am just puzzled by code working in 12.0 and suddenly breaking 12.1.

[image]

Comment: No problem with version 12.1 on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 1):

I also have encountered this bug in 12.1. It has been reported to WRI already. It can be mitigated by choosing the RasterSize an integer multiple of the ImageSize:

```
lpd = ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 
     2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All, PlotLabel -> "HELLO WORLD", 
   FrameLabel -> {"HELLO WORLD", "HELLO WORLD"}, ImageSize -> 500];
lp = ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], PlotLabel -> "HELLO WORLD", 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"HELLO WORLD", "HELLO WORLD"}, 
   ImageSize -> 500];

numRaster = 4000;
Rasterize[lp, RasterSize -> numRaster]
Rasterize[lpd, RasterSize -> numRaster]
```

which works as it should. (at least on Mac)

Comment: On my Mac with v12.1 and using your code, there are still problems with the labels for the ListDensityPlot.

Comment: Have you tried RasterSize 1000? or 2000? Depending on your setup the maximum 'drawing buffer' is 4096*4096 or 8192*8192 (including HiDPI stuff and so on).

Comment: There are still problems with `numRaster = 2000` or `numRaster = 1000`

Comment: This seems to be a good workaround for me. My issue was during export, as I assume `Rasterize` is called at some point during that process. With `ImageSize -> 500` and `Export["~/Desktop/test.png", plot, RasterSize -> 4000, ImageResolution -> 300]`, I got the correct output.

Comment: From what I understood, this is internally already fixed, and might appear in a future update.